# Bilerping a 2D python array results in more values than expected. Can anyone explain this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf

When I run the code below I get 
(24, 170, 180)
(29559,)

as the answer for my print statements(printing shapes of arrays).
Shape of the original data set I use is (24, 170, 180). So the current dataset dataArr has dimensions 170*180. I fixed the time t=10(has dimension 24 here)I iterate through the 2d array and bilerp a cell (four data points- i,j i+1,j, i,j+1, i+1,j+1) into one value and append to self.tempY array. So the value I should get for the shape of self.tempY array is 170*180. But the result set has 29904 values. Why do I get this value?

```
def compute(self,varval):      
    vars=self.data.variables
    for var in vars:
        if var==varval:
            ntimes, ny, nx=vars[var].shape #inherit the method above.
    print(ntimes, ny, nx)
    #create the old computational grid.
    computational_grid=np.zeros((ny,nx),dtype=int) 
    fraction=.5 
    newnx,newny =(nx*fraction,ny*fraction)
    new_computational_grid=np.zeros((newny,newnx),dtype=int)
    phy_value_arr=self.get_data(varval)
    t=10 #send this t value with coords
    dataArr=self.data.variables['tos'][t]     
    for j in range(1,(nx-2),1):
        for i in range(1,(ny-2),1):
           a=self.Lerp((dataArr[i][j+1]),(dataArr[i+1][j+1]),fraction)
           b=self.Lerp((dataArr[i][j]),(dataArr[i+1][j]),fraction)
           self.tempY.append(self.Lerp(a,b,fraction))
    smallgridarray = np.asarray(self.tempY)
    print(smallgridarray.shape)
def Lerp(self, _a, _b, _t) :
  return _a+(_b-_a)*_t
```

Comment: Could you provide some example of input data? How do we call this method to check the results ourself? what is expected output for a given input?

Comment: I have a netcdf dataset that I use in this method.  It has several variables where tos is the one I'm concerned with . self.get_data(varval) is a 3d array consisting time longitude and latutude. I get a slice out of the 3d array where t=10 and try to get the average value of the cells in this 2d plane. This plane has shape 170*180 with that many points. I'm trying to bilerp each cell in this plane and generate the value array. Does that help?

Comment: I printed the nx value and ny value and they are 180 and 170. If I print the dataArr I get something like this. I'm wondering if the blank values are giving any problem as well.

Comment: [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [271.42236328125 271.422607421875 271.4228820800781 ..., 271.4221496582031
  271.4220886230469 271.4221496582031]
 [271.432373046875 271.43243408203125 271.4325256347656 ...,
  271.4322204589844 271.4322814941406 271.4323425292969]
 [271.4455261230469 271.4455261230469 271.4455261230469 ...,
  271.445556640625 271.445556640625 271.445556640625]]

Answer (score 0):

Okay  I figured out why! Its the correct no of points I get from nx-2 *ny-2
i.e: 168*178